# Azure Functions HttpTrigger all properties null on int overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, azure-functions

I use some Azure Functions as WebApi. Now I have the following DTO to create a vehicle:

```
public class CreateVehicleDto
{
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int? Mileage { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

My method header looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("CreateVehicle")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ReadVehicleDto>> CreateVehicle([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "vehicles")] CreateVehicleDto createVehicleDto){}
```

The problem is that when my client sends a mileage higher than `int.MaxValue` all properties of the DTO are `null` and the method runs without throwing any exception whatsoever.

Is there a way to handle that? In case of a too high mileage I want to return a `BadRequestResult`.

I've also tried to use the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to set a maximum like this `[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]` and validate it with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator`. But when the object gets validated it's already too late because all properties of the DTO get passed into the method with a value of `null`.

Comment: for local testing sake, try updating Mileage to `string` type and in `CreateVehicle` method use `int.TryParse` to return `BadRequestResult` accordingly. I am curious about why all properties are null when mileage overflows `int` value

Comment: Yes that would be a workaround but is there any way to catch this problem like in a middleware or something. I'm also curious why the api doesn't throw an exception or return a 500 result but instead just continues running with all properties set to null.

Comment: I guess this is because deserialization to an object fails and you can simply not partially deserialize an object. So what you want is not doable. You could also change the int to a long allowing a much larger value and then try to parse is back to an int in your code.

Comment: The solution with long as type won't change anything because the client could send a value higher than the max long value and it would result in the same problem.

When the deserialization fails an exception should be thrown which you can then handle in a middleware.
So I'm waiting for .NET 6 when there is proper support for middlewares in azure functions.